# Getting syntax error on developer tools

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm getting an unexpected syntax error: unexpected token [

Here is my code.

```
$ajaxString = "";
foreach ($z as $key => $val) {
    $ajaxString .= "image[]=$val&";
}
$ajaxString = substr($ajaxString,0,-1);

$DATA .= "
    <div class='order-item-info'>
        <div class='order-item-download-all'>
            <input type='image' src='images/download-all.png' alt='Submit' onclick='download(".$ajaxString.")'>
        </div>
    </div>\n";
```

My code on the developer tools looks like this.

```
<input type='image' src='download-all.png' alt='Submit' onclick='download(image[]=Logo.jpg&image[]=Logo_Large.jpg&image[]=)'>
```

I know I'm missing something, just can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter to the `download` function should be a string. As it is, it is not. Change the code: (snippet)

```
<input type='image' src='images/download-all.png' alt='Submit' onclick='download(\"".$ajaxString."\")'>
```

so that it produces the following

```
<input type='image' src='download-all.png' alt='Submit' onclick='download("image[]=Logo.jpg&image[]=Logo_Large.jpg&image[]=")'>
```

Comment: better yet, simply do `echo json_encode($ajaxString)`, which takes care of all that.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wasn't aware of that. I was thinking my original double quotes would do the job.